# Where to find app url link in App Store Connect for beta app in the year 2019?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-id

Let me start with my is approved for external beta testers.

[image]

I looked for the answer to this question and kept coming across old answers that referenced `iTunes Connect` and were posted in 2015, 2016, 2017.

This is now 2019 and `iTunes Connect` has been renamed to `App Store Connect` and the layout has changed.

When my previous app was in beta, to get the App Store url I would have to go to `iTunes Connect` > `MyApps` (select the app I wanted) > `App Information` > and at the bottom there was a link that said `View on App Store`. Clicking that link would bring me to a blank page with my not yet live url as the url for my beta app.

[image]

At one time on `iTunes Connect` there was a `More` [button that brought you there](https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201574352-Add-Your-App-s-Apple-App-Store-URL-to-your-Landing-Page)

[image]

The new `App Store Connect` layout doesn't have the `View on App Store` at the bottom anymore nor a `More` button listed in any visible area

[image]

I understand the App Store url link is formatted as follows and I can manually enter in the data myself:

```
"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/MY_APP_NAME/idMy_APP_ID?mt=8" // this is what I previously used that worked fine
```

or

```
"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/[appName]/[appID]" // I never used this, I found a couple of answers that said this is the new format??? I can't the link in App Store Connect to verify if this is true or not
```

But this is **prone to typographical error**. Who's ridiculous idea was it to change/remove/hide the `View on App Store` link and I now have to go to Stack Overflow  to get a link and manually type or c+p this data in which can lead to an incorrect character being entered???

**Anyhow where can I find the link to my beta app in App Store Connect in 2019** and presumably in 2020 unless they change it again for no apparent reason?

Comment: it's display after the live app once.

Comment: before I was able to get it when the app wasn't live. My app is beta approved for external testers and it's not visible

Comment: for which purpose you need to put inside app ?

Comment: what does have to do with anything?

Comment: in my app, i need app url to open app store link when i want to update app forcefully. now, apple are given link after 1 version live. it's basically true because first version no need to "force update".

Comment: if you have these types of requirements then no need to worry we can give force update to app after getting url.

Comment: for umpteen years they let developers have access to the link. Whatever a developer decided to do with that link was up to the dev. Using the manual links in my answer I still have access to the url that my app will use. The url isn't a mystery until after your link is live because you can find the format via numerous answers on SO. The question is where did they move the link to inside App Store Connect.

Comment: they didn't move link. they are just showing link after your app ready for sale.

Comment: Where is the **View on App Store** now located inside App Store Connect? That's the question here.

Comment: same as before inside "App Information --> Additional Information". if your app is not ready for sale then you can't see that button. after your app is live you can see that button.

Comment: So you're saying that beta apps that have been approved for external testers no longer have access to this information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197861/discussion-between-nirav-kotecha-and-lance-samaria).

Comment: @NiravKotecha post your comment as an answer. If what you says is correct I will choose it since you said it first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After updating new design of iTunes connect, apple has removed **"View on App Store"** button option to see your app link.

It's only display when your app is **Approved by apple** (first time). after it will always visible for that app.

Another option for us until apple will enable that option:

`https://apps.apple.com/app/id{{appId}}`

Reference: https://help.swiftic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201574352-Add-Your-App-s-Apple-App-Store-URL-to-your-Landing-Page

Comment: I’ll let you know in s few hours. I’ll call around 11am

Comment: Status must not be ready for sale. Can also be pending developer release or similar. Version just needs to be approved by Apple.

Comment: There are probably even more states where this appears. Just see my answer ;-)

Comment: @NiravKotecha I just emailed them, I'll let you know the answer when they respond. It wouldn't let me call

Comment: @LanceSamaria any response received ?

Comment: @NiravKotecha nope nothing, I checked my reg email inbox and junk and nothing? There’s a way I can call if I pick another category, I’ll try it today and get back to

Comment: @NiravKotecha they just emailed, I added their response as part of the answer. Once they respond I'll update the answer with it https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527761/4833705

Comment: Their response, you was correct, thanks for the help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527761/4833705

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: It's only there once the app has **at least one** `live version` (= version that got approved by Apple).

I'm not sure why they removed it and you might file a bug report with Apple over here: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

The easiest way to construct the link is:

`https://apps.apple.com/app/id{{appId}}`

App name is optional and can be different for different languages. Same goes for the storefront identifier. (https://apps.apple.com/de/app/id529479190 -> German vs. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id529479190 English (U.S.)

Comment: That’s the same thing @NiravKotecha said in the comments when I first posted the question. I’m going to call Apple today and see what they say. It’s odd that they would remove it knowing SO exists.

Comment: @LanceSamaria yes, you can contact with apple and let us know what they tells.

Comment: I doubt they will tell you why they changed the interface.

Comment: @Max Yeah I doubt a tech person would know that anyway, seems like they have bigger fish to fry. I didn't ask why they changed the interface I just asked where they moved it to. Maybe they renamed it or there's another way to access it for beta. I just emailed them, let's see what they say in response. I'll keep you updated. Thanks!

Comment: Their response, you was correct, thanks for the help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57527761/4833705. I upvoted your answer but picked NiravKotecha's because he did say it first. Thanks for the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Apple about this issue and this isn't an answer but the response they sent me fo far. I'll add the rest to it after they respond to my response:

> Hello Lance,
>
> Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Program Support. My name is
>   Leo and I was glad to review your case. I understand that . You've
>   come to the right place and I will be glad to help you.   So that we
>   can best assist you, what URL are you trying to find? Are you looking
>   for an URL that leads to your app for a customer to find on the App
>   Store? Or, are you looking for an URL that is in your scope as a
>   developer?
>
> Also, please provide the following, if applicable:
>
> • Steps to reproduce the issue • Approximate date and time the error
>   occurred (including the time zone) • Full-window screenshots or video
>   illustrating the issue • Username of each user experiencing the issue
>   • Web browsers that you were able to reproduce the issue in • Web
>   browser version numbers
>
> After we receive the requested information, we will investigate
>   further and let you know when we have an update.   If you have any
>   additional questions, please don’t hesitate to contact us here.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/contact/
>
> For your reference, the case number for this correspondence is
>   xxxxxxx88535.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Leo Apple Inc.

**My Response**

> Hello Leo,
>
> My app is currently in beta, it isn't live in the App Store yet so I
>   have no customers and even if I did they wouldn't be able to download
>   the app in beta via the App Store.
>
> iTunes Connect has been renamed to App Store Connect. I would like to
>   know where did you move the link that was initially under iTunes
>   Connect > MyApps  > App Information > and at the bottom there was a
>   link that said View on App Store.
>
> Even while in beta that link gave me the eventual link to my app
>   inside the AppStore once it went live so customers would be able to
>   download it. The url was constructed as:
>   "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/MY_APP_NAME/idMy_APP_ID?mt=8"
>
> Where can I now find the "View on App Store" link inside App Store
>   Connect?

**Here is their final response**

> Hello Lance,
>
> My name is Austin and I am a Senior Advisor with Apple Developer
>   Program Support. I will be your new point of contact for this case.
>
> I understand you are inquiring about the “View on App Store” option
>   not showing for your app records. As your account does not have any
>   apps on the App Store, this is expected behavior as this would not
>   provide any function until an app is available on the App Store.
>
> Please let me know if you have any further questions and I will be
>   happy to assist you further.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same question, and I've ended up here.

We needed a link to our application which could be visible through the browser if you're not working on iOS. Our application is set to **availability** to only **one country** (Croatia).

`https://apps.apple.com/app/id{{appId}}` opens iTunes or AppCenter app.

If you're going through App Store Connect, button **View on App Store** generates link `https://apps.apple.com/`**us**`/app/id{{appId}}` and the link still opens iTunes or AppCenter app, as app is not available in the US.

When I've switched to our wanted country code `https://apps.apple.com/`**hr**`/app/id{{appId}}` link opens inside a browser and everything works fine.

I hope that this answer will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Under  **Additional Information** in **General >** **App Information** section, click **View on App Store**. It opens a new tab that has the following url if the primaray lanauge of your app is **English (U.S.)**.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/you-app-name/idXXXXXXXX

---

Remove `/us` and `/your-app-name` to create a universal link. The new url will be

https://apps.apple.com/app/idXXXXXXXX where **XXXXXXXX** id of your app.